# Devise: My customer data is not available anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I made a big mistake and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I originally installed Devise the proper way, but today I decided to create a second instance of user using the following terminal line:

```
rails g controller Users index
```

Now I realize this was not the right thing to do, and I decided to destroy the generated code as with this command:

```
rails destroy controller Users
```

Now nothing works and I get the following error when accessing the sign up view:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant CustomersController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Here's my route file

```
 devise_for :users
  root :to => 'events#index'
```

What am I supposed to do in this case???

Comment: Did you override any devise controllers?

Comment: well i am assuming by doing rails g controller User it overided my User devise controller produced by rails g devise User. Sorry yes i did overide i believe and update my route file just to show. is there any i can do or start from scractch his pretty much my only option?

Comment: If you have to do it from scratch you might consider some source control management this time around.

Comment: You might have to start over, is the Customers Controller using devise? I cannot be certain which controllers were destroyed by that command. Are you using Git??

Comment: I see, pretty much customer was my user, but i just for the sake of writing down the problem to u guys, i decided to use user. Aka User = Customer. So if i understand overiding it is just not something to do